# jQuery UI Tabs - styling Headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Is there any way that I can "Stack" the jQuery UI Tabs Header?  Please allow me to explain:  I have tabs which may require two or more words for the titles to be self-explanatory.  For instance:

"PDP Undeveloped"

My problem is that I am running out of space when adding a bunch of tabs.  So instead of writing the tab as

```
PDP Undeveloped
```

I would like it to show as

```
    PDP
Undeveloped
```

Is that possible?  If not then are there alternate ways of solving this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Bharat

Comment: Automatically you mean? So when the width has been exceeded, force tabs to wrap on whitespace?

Comment: I was hoping that I could explicitly force it to break at the end of certain words.  Something similar to <br/> tag in HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `<br />` tags.  Since you only want them to take effect when you're short on space I'd recommend using media queries to turn on the multi line display.

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc <br />tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin <br />dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean <br />lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">Tab 1</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">Tab 2</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">Tab 3</div>
</div>

<style>
    br { display: none; }

    /* Replace 700px with whatever width you want the multi line display to start */
    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        .ui-tabs li { height: 4em; }    
        br { display: inline; }
    }
</style>
```

**Live example**: http://jsfiddle.net/vvpeF/

Comment: Thank you.  It works perfectly!  I do have a follow up question though, The tabs are shown with only half the height if I have only one word.  Is there a way to put invisible space on the next line so that ALL tabs have the same height?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no way of doing this without setting an explicit ```height``` on ```..ui-tabs li``` like I did in my example.  There's a jQuery UI bug to add some mechanism of doing this that would be similar to the accordion plugin's ```autoHeight``` and ```fillSpace``` options (http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#option-autoHeight) - http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8345.

Comment: Thanks.  I found a rather workable solution to this problem.  Turns out that if I use non-breaking space html entity (&nbsp), I get the desired effect :)